# .Net WebApi - CustomValidation methods called twice

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-web-api

Steps to replicate:

- Start a new .Net WebApi 2 project
- Alter the `ValuesController` to have a method: `public string Get([FromUri] Input input)`
- Create the Input model class with one property:

  `[CustomValidation(typeof(StringValidator), "Validate")]
  public string Thing { get; set; }`
- Create a simple `StringValidator` class with a `Validate` method that just returns `ValidationResult/.Success`, and stick a breakpoint in the method.
- Start up the API and call the method like so: `http://localhost:49394/api/values?thing=something`
- The breakpoint will be hit twice, and both times the value passed in will be "something"

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? I've tried removing the default `ActionDescriptorFilterProvider` from the filters in `HttpConfiguration`, but that still causes the validation method to be triggered twice.

Answer (score 1):

It runs validation after `set` and `get`. Remove `set` from the `Thing` property and validation method will run only once.

Comment: Hey, cheers for the reply. Without the setter though the framework has no way to set the value :). Do you know if there is a way to specify validation only on Set, and not on Get?

Comment: Yeah seems like it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in net core 3.1 API. In my case the ApiController was doing the first validation while i was triggering the second validation manually in the controller.

I solved this issue by disabling the built-in validation in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers(o => {
      o.ModelValidatorProviders.Clear(); 
});
```

Be aware that this will disable validation completely on all controllers. You can still validate the models manually though.